# Check if login already added in User Defined Database Role

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a script to add a Login to a user-defined role, where it will take `RoleName` and `Login` as input parameters.

Checking if already exist before adding, but the following check is returning NULL.

```
USE [MYDatabase];
DECLARE @AddUser NVARCHAR(100) = 'test'
DECLARE @RoleName NVARCHAR(100) = 'MYDatabase_ReadOnly' -- User Defined DB ROle
IF EXISTS (Select name from sys.database_principals where name = @RoleName)
BEGIN
    SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER (@RoleName, @AddUser)
    --Output: NULL
END
```

I can see both `test` and `MYDatabase_ReadOnly` available in `sys.database_principals`.

What I am missing here? (I am doing it in SQL Server 2014)

Comment: What `type` is the user in `sys.database_principals`, 'S' or 'U'?

Comment: type for 'test' is 'S'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be `IS_ROLEMEMBER(@RoleName, @AddUser)` as it is checking for the database role instead of `IS_SRVROLEMEMBER (@RoleName, @AddUser)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Syntax: IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ( 'role' [ , 'login' ] )  
--Return value as NULL indicates role or login is not valid, or you do not have permission to view the role membership
--Return value as 0 indicates login is not a member of role.
--Return value as 1 indicates login is a member of role.

--I think you are using rong value for role paramenter.(Use role value from below)
--sysadmin,bcreator,bulkadmin,diskadmin,public,processadmin 

USE [MYDatabase];
DECLARE @database_principals_name NVARCHAR(100) = 'db_owner'
DECLARE @RoleName NVARCHAR(100) = 'sysadmin' -- User Defined DB ROle
IF EXISTS (Select name from sys.database_principals where name = @database_principals_name)
BEGIN
    select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')
    --Output: NULL
END
```